# google picasa video is not playing in jwplayer

Tags: google-drive-api, html5-video, jwplayer, mp4, google-photos

I uploaded my video in google photos and then try to play the link in jwplayer using the below script which plays google drive videos easily but it is not playing video of google photos. is this "google-drive-player-script" can play the video from google photos with some modification.?

```
$file = '[{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "360p", "file": "test.mp4"}]';
<script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("myElement").setup({
            playlist: [{
                "sources":<?php echo $file?>,

            }],
            allowfullscreen: true,
            width: '100%',
            aspectratio: '16:9',
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You may refer with this [sample tutorial](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1480872) that uses the JavaScript API to load new videos into JW Player. Just make sure that you have uploaded a copy of JW Player and included the script in the `<head>` of your page, together with your player key. See the [MP4 Video Embed](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-mp4-video-embed) article for more info.

Comment: @abielita did you read what is my question? i am not asking how to embed jwplayer. I am asking  how to play google picasa video.